# Unable to show Dashboard of fabric

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have installed the fabric, integrated jar files and API key.

I installed fabric plugin, sign in, crashlytics, answers, and crash.

In gradle, I add 2 meta data in `AndroidManifest`.

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="***" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
```

I add maven and... in project gradle.

```
maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.2.0'
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
```

I did all the necessary work, but fabric dashboard is not showing.
None of 3 steps have been taken, but I do it all.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin from Fabric/Firebase here - are you integrating with Fabric or Firebase Crashlytics instructions (https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install vs https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android)?

If you reach out to support@fabric.io with your app's package name and a link to this post, we can take a closer look at what's going wrong with the onboarding process for your app.